# How to View 3D building view angle in open layers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, cesiumjs

How we can see 3D building view angle in open layers like google earth 3D map.

Click here for image

[image: 1]

Please see my image what i want in open layers map.

I want to create 3D building view in open layers but I have no idea how we can do this.

anyone can help me to create 3D building view in open layers.

Answer (score 0):

for such applications you should better look at Cesium.js. There was also a Cesium implementation for OpenLayers, but I don't know if there is still something going on: https://openlayers.org/ol-cesium/

Greetings Sven

Comment: can you show me the demo for 3D building view.